# Why is a tensor times its dual a derivative?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, beyond-the-standard-model, axion

Why is a term like

$$F \tilde{F}$$

or

$$G \tilde{G}$$

considered to be a derivative? Where are the derivatives?

This is said in a [PRD article](http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.6088). Check section IV page 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In gauge theory, we usually consider the gauge field $A^\mu$ to be fundamental. The field strength is defined as

$$F_{\mu\nu}=\partial_{[\mu}A_{\nu]}-[A_\mu,A_\nu]$$

Hopefully it is now clear that

$$F\tilde F=F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$$

contains a kinetic term, plus some derivative interaction terms. I believe this is what Graham and Rajendran are referring to in the article you linked.

Comment: Yes - my answer applies for a general gauge theory, so both QED and QCD are covered.

Comment: @EdwardHughes are you sure that the dual tensor is just F? Personally, I would expect it to be the Hodge dual differential form. The $F\tilde{F}$ term is then a 4-divergence of some vector field, which is probably the answer to the question. What do you think?

Comment: You are right that $\tilde F$ is the Hodge dual. As far as I remember the wedge product of a tensor and it's Hodge dual can be written as $F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}$ once you've dealt with all the Levi-Civita symbols. The explicit calculation is easy to check (and should be in any good textbook on gauge theory).

Comment: @EdwardHughes yes, you are right. Probably would be better to include this in your answer though.